LiveWire v3 Dispatch Method Does Not Show Bootstrap Modal In Laravel v11
I'm working with Laravel v11 and wanted to show a Modal on users list blade when clicking on Add New Button:
<div class="card-header">
   <div class="card-tools">
      <button type="button" wire:click="addNew">Add New</button>
   </div>
</div>

And this is App\Livewire\Admin\Users\ListUsers Class:
class ListUsers extends Component
{
    public $users;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function mount()
    {
        // Fetching users from the database
        $this->users = User::all();
    }

    public function addNew()
    {
        // Trigger modal open event
        $this->dispatch('showModal');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // Save logic
        User::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ]);

        // Reset input fields
        $this->reset('name', 'email');

        // Close the modal after saving
        $this->dispatch('closeModal');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.users.list-users')->layout('layouts.app');
    }
}

But now when clicking on Modal, I get this at Console Bar and nothing appears as Modal:
capture
So what's going wrong here? How can I show the Modal properly in this case?
Note that I'm using "livewire/livewire": "^3.5"
And here is the script in `list-users` blade:
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        Livewire.on('showModal', () => {
            const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            if (modal) {
                modal.style.display = 'block'; // Show the modal
            }
        });

        // Close modal when the close button is clicked
        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            if (event.target.classList.contains('close')) {
                modal.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the modal
            }
        });
    });
</script>

